# how to set global variables from callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What i'm have:
I have 3 request's in my node app with some callback
I want to make global varibale like 
`var a`
`callback1` will make `a = 'something'`
`callback2` will make `a = 'another something`
`callback3` will make `a = 'another another'`
`console.log(a)`
So, how to make this?

Comment: Please look into promises. You do not need global variables

Comment: Using Global variable is not advisable. If you need to modify it .. it's a code smell and you need to look into the logic of your code.

Comment: Please show the actual code you're trying to make work because using a global variable is nearly always the wrong solution.  If you show your actual code and describe what you're trying to accomplish, then people here could show you the proper way to code it.  As your question stands now, the only piece of advice we can offer is to stop using a global variable as it's the wrong solution.

Comment: Add your code to it .

Answer (score 0):

Declare "var a" outside your callback function and when get callback assign it to var a and it will available throughout your code. Every time you get new callback assign it to var a.